Regex para eliminar paréntesis no balanceados en R
Tengo la siguiente cadena:
s <- "A) Las cadenas quedan (por mucho) fuera de casai)El cielo es azul"

¿Cómo construir un patrón que permita remover el parpentesis y UN caracter atrás solo en aquellos casos en los que halla paréntesis de cierre pero no de apertura (por ejemplo A) e i))? Por ejemplo, (por mucho) está balanceado por lo que NO debo reemplazar 'o)'.
La salida esperada (si el reemplazo se hace por '~'):
"~Las cadenas quedan (por mucho) fuera de casa~El cielo es azul"`


Por acá una regex que busca el patrón de enumeración, tanto con mayúscula, como el caso de A) y el de enumeración con patrón i), ii), iii) o iv) y hará el reemplazo deseado:
> gsub("[[:upper:]i*]\\)\\s*", "~", s) 
[1] "~Las cadenas quedan (por mucho) fuera de casa~El cielo es azul"


El paréntesis es un caracter especial, entonces para que deje de ser especial, se le agrega \\ a su atrás. Asimismo, para hacer referencia a la letra anterior, se podría usar la expresión regular . que hace referencia a cualquier caracter.
En ese sentido, el código sería el siguiente:
gsub(".\\)","~",s)

Resultado:
"~ Las cadenas quedan (por much~ fuera de casa~El cielo es azul"


Este no es el resultado deseado. Nota que (por mucho) debe permanecer igual y en tu resultado se ve afectado.
